# Excel copy a range of cells to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

In the first workbook, after I filter all the cells, I have to copy the first 20 rows into another workbook.

This is my code, but I don't know how to make it copy the first 20 rows:

```
Range("AN2:AP1000").Select
Range("A2:A1000").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Workbook2").Activate
Range("O15:Q35").Select
Range("N15:N35").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I have 2 ranges because the data to copy is on 2 different columns.
This is the table to be copied(first 20 rows of data):
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phmBV.png)

Comment: I guess you cant... you need to copy and paste twice

Comment: AN2:AP1000 is inside the range of A2:A1000 so you can just copy and paste A2:A1000

Comment: Also why are you copying 1000 rows if you just want to copy 20 rows?

Comment: Because I have 1000 rows and after I filter my data,I could have one at row 400

Comment: Ah...then you may just need to paste to `range("O15")` and `range("N15")`

Comment: But by using Range("AN2:AP1000").Select it just pastes more than 20 data, that s the one I have to adjust, if I choose AP20, that just selectes 2 rows of data. I dont know what's wrong...

Comment: I was just saying to paste to one cell, not a range of cells. @Harassed Dad answer is correct as the code is not selecting the cells, that way just the visible cells will be copied., but I would still recommend to just paste to O15 and N15

Comment: His code doesn't work...

Comment: I have posted an update with an image of the table to be copied

Answer (score 0):

Never use select or activate - use range variables instead

```
dim Source1 as range
dim source2 as range
dim dest1 as range
dim dest2 as range
set source1 = Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
set source2 = Range("AN2:AP1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
with Workbooks("Workbook2").worksheets(1)  'i assume first sheet
     set dest1 = .Range("O15") 
     set dest2 = .Range("N15")
end with
source1.copy dest1
source2.copy dest2
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors from with windows and the range from dest1

Comment: is there actually a Workbook2 open when you run it? Are you sure it's not named Workbook2.xlsx ?

Comment: Yes, it is opened and it's an xlsm. I put the extension but it still gives me this error: "Object doesn't support the property or method"

Comment: Sorry, I had a senile moment - it's workbook not windows - see edit in my answer